# Why Git ignores ~/.ssh/id_rsa, wants ~/.ssh/id_dsa or ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa?

Tags: git, ssh

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
no such identity: /home/eduan/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
no such identity: /home/eduan/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
```

That's what happens when I try to push, or in this case when I do `ssh -T git@github.com`.

I have correctly generated the id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.

How may I go about solving this? I'm using Arch Linux with E17 BTW.

**EDIT**:
Regarding [the answer by @kostix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16065154/16821502), who also edited this question: Would the below work for this?

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It doesn't seem to work for me yet... I get the following when I push with Git:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I made sure the repo exists, and I also updated the remote URL with `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Greduan/dotfiles.git`.

I also added the SSH key to the list of accepted SSH keys in GitHub. What else should I do?

Comment: in order to debug an issue like that I use `echo "ssh -v -v -v $@" > ssh_debug_wrapper` and then I launch 
`GIT_SSH="./ssh_debug_wrapper" git push`. I hope this help you at least to understand better the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SSH client tells you about `id_dsa` (note the "d" — it stands for DSA) while you've generated `id_rsa` (note the "r" which stands for RSA).

You should either generate a DSA key or tell SSH which "identity" (the private key) to use. This could be done using the `IdentityFile` directive under a custom `Host` entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file for the `github` remote (see the `ssh_config(5)` manual page).

**Update** (2013-04-29, to make it clearer for the next reader). The essense of the problem was that the OP has wrong owner (root) on his `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key, so the OpenSSH client first tried to read that key, failed, and then went on trying to read `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, in turn, which also failed — this time because they simply did not exist. Having no more keys to use for pubkey authentication and no available authentication mechanisms, the SSH client failed. Those "No such identity ..." messages were actually warnings.

Comment: I see... That certainly makes sense. Could you check my edits?

Comment: @Eduan, `github` is not equal to `github.com` so as it stands your `Host` entry has no chance to work.

Comment: @Eduan, I mean, as is explained in the `ssh_config(5)` manual page, tne token specified in a `Host` entry must match what you use when calling SSH. This is subject to a set of "glob-style" matching rules, but for `github.com` you should supposedly use `github.com`, literally. Alternatively, you could provide the `HostName` entry under the `Host` directive but then you must use just `github` when telling the SSH client where to connect. I'd go for the first.

Comment: @Eduan, do `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -vvvv git@github.com` and try to parse its debug output. Check to see if it really tried to send its key to the server and got it rejected.

Comment: @Eduan, do `ssh-keygen -l ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and verify the fingerprint it shows exactly matches the fingerprint of a key you see in your github account settings.

Comment: Results of the first test: https://gist.github.com/Greduan/75a471de9e8c959489a6 The second test I confirmed it is the same...

Comment: @Eduan, lines 93 and 100: the SSH client is unable to read your private key file. My guess is that for some reason you've generated it as root. If so, `chown eduan` and then `chmod 0600` that file. The public part might have 0644 access mode.

Comment: @Eduan, now I think that originally we were quite probably chasing a wrong problem so I would now try to comment out those github-specific entries in `~/.ssh/config` and see if it still works.

Comment: Removing that does not generate the problem again. Thanks for reminding me to delete it. :)